# python - most efficient code to search for, and replace, given word in a sentence?

Tags: python, string, replace, character

I'm working through simple exercises in an online Python course - an exercise called "censor" takes 2 inputs, a sentence and word - then returns the sentence with all instances of the given word replaced by asterisks. The number of asterisks in each replacement equals the number of characters in the original word. For simplicity's sake the exercise assumes no input error checking is needed. My code works but I'm wondering if it can be made more efficient?:

```
def censor(text, word):
    textList = text.split()
    for index, item in enumerate(textList):
        count = 0
        if item == word:
            for char in word:
                count += 1
            strikeout = "*" * count
            textList[index] = strikeout
            result = ' '.join(textList)
    return result
```

Comment: *"My code works but I'm wondering if it can be made more efficient?"* That typically is better suited question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For a start, note that `textList[index] = '*' * len(word)` would be neater and probably more efficient than the separate `count` loop.

Comment: Am still pretty new to this forum. Lots of "rules" to absorb it seems :-) Is there a way for me to move it, rather than needing to re-enter?... And... I thought I was just in a general, "post any question" area... how do I identify the sub-forum I'm in?

Comment: It says that on the top of the screen.

Comment: Actually, I just see "Stack Overflow" which I thought was the overarching title for a 'family' of various category-specific sites (such, as apparently" a "Code Review" site?

Comment: The overreaching title for these q&a sites is Stack **Exchange**

Comment: @ppperry It's sort of Stack Exchange but then the company itself *is* called Stack Overflow so it's not the clearest.

Comment: The name of the company that owns/runs/created all these sites: "Stack Overflow"

Comment: The collective name for all these sites: The Stack Exchange Network

Comment: The individual site you're browsing / posting on: "Stack Overflow", "Code Review", "Electrical Engineering", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already a function on string objects that does this:

```
def censor(text,word):
    return text.replace(word, "*"*len(word))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Glad your answer made it through before I got shut down. If I can find it, I'll check out the Python source for .replace and see how they did it. Go straight to the source, as it were :-)

Comment: You should accept my answer then. Also, the python source for built in functions is written in C.